# Display uploaded image without page refresh?

Tags: image-uploading

I have uploaded an image to the server without page load. My question is that what is the best way to display it after successful upload in the browser without page load ??

```
   html part---->
     <form method="post" data-remote="true" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/update_profile_image" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_user_72" class="edit_user">

      <div>
         <input type="file" id="user_avatar" name="user[avatar]" as="file">
       </div>
     <input type = "button" value ="Update" id= "update-img" 
      onclick ="AjaxUpdateImage($('form').attr('action'),$('form').attr('id'))" />
</form>


        ajax part--->

       function AjaxUpdateImage(url,id) {
       var formData = new FormData($('#'+id)[0]);
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       processData: false, // Don't process the files
       contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
       data: formData, // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function (data)
       {
            console.log(data)
       }
  })



   server part (ruby on rails)---->

       def update_profile_image
        id = params[:user][:attr].to_i
        @user = User.find(id)
        @response = @user.update_attribute(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar])
        respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @response }
       end
      end
```

Comment: Can you please show us at least sample of your code? So that, we can understand what your problem is. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the code